# Windows 10 with Azure Local Cluster shows 8TB virtual size on 1TB physical disk

Tags: azure

I installed the Azure Local Cluster on my Windows 10 Home edition. 
The installation created directory C:/SfDevCluster/

When I run the Properties command on C:/SfDevCluster/, Size is 8.06 TB, Size on disk is 10 GB. However, the physical size of my disk is only 1 TB.
I went through all the tabs in the Properties dialog box looking for
some hints about virtual size but no clues. I went through all
system/administrative tools and no clue about virtual disks.
What feature of Windows 10 enables this virtual size?
Whatever it is, there has to be a way to map it into some
external storage but how? What is the name for this feature so I can research it.

Answer (score 0):

storage spaces thin provisioning probably does, possibly in combination with dynamic vhd(x) underneath.

lotsa resources lying around:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx#What_happens_if_I_run_out_of_physical_capacity_on_a_thinly_provisioned_storage_space
https://serverfault.com/questions/591125/how-can-i-safely-use-storage-thin-provisioning (more general)